# Return the correct status searching the records

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, performance, time-complexity

Task description:

> Please provide an implementation that searches the records and returns the correct user_status at the given date. You can imagine the records as single events which get fired on a user status change. If a user starts paying, there will be one record stored with status paying, whereas if this user stops paying, there will be another record added with status cancelled. Consequently a user remains in status paying until the next cancelled event. In case there is no status available for a specific date, simply return non-paying. The valid responses that should be provided are: paying, cancelled or non-paying.

Records are stored in the json file:

```
RECORDS = [
        {'user_id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-01-01T10:00:00', 'status': 'paying'},
        {'user_id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-03-01T19:00:00', 'status': 'paying'},
        {'user_id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-02-01T12:00:00', 'status': 'cancelled'},
        {'user_id': 3, 'created_at': '2017-10-01T10:00:00', 'status': 'paying'},
        {'user_id': 3, 'created_at': '2016-02-01T05:00:00', 'status': 'cancelled'},
    ]
```

**Question**: How should I find the user status and use this json file spending less time (time complexity) as possible?

Comment: there is no user status in json

Comment: @deadshot, sorry, updated the file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no further information has been provided about the ordering of the data, I think this one of the closest attempts to achieving optimal complexity  [ << n*log(n)].

```
def get_user_status(user_id, records):

    # base case
     if not records:
        return 'non-paying'

    # create a dictionary to store the user status and date of status
    user_status = {}
    for record in records:
        if record['user_id'] == user_id:
            user_status[record['created_at']] = record['status']

    # sort the date
    user_status_list = sorted(user_status.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])

    # user status is basically most recent status, return if it exists
    if user_status_list:
        return user_status_list[-1][1]

    # if no status, return non-paying
    else:
        return 'non-paying'
```

Further optimisation can be done if it is the case that we may have to perform these lookups multiple times. Most straight forward approach would be to have a hashmap of a hashmap and update user_status based on new record update so we don't have to perform a linear sweep each time.